# Is there a way I can run a specified .spec file once all "x" .spec files have been run? Cypress

Tags: parallel-processing, cypress

I want to do some clearing up after all .spec files have been run by Cypress. For this I created another .spec file that does several API calls. I need Cypress to run this .spec file only after all tests form all the other files have ran. One more thing, my .spec files are being run by Cypress in parallel mode, via 4 machines.

I found out there are the "after" hooks I could use, but as far as I read, these hooks apply per only one .spec file, not all of them.

Answer (score 3):

To run a single spec out of process, take a look at the [Module Api](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Examples).

With this you can create a node script that can be run after all parallel processes have completed.

**./scripts/e2e-run-cleanup.js**

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress
  .run({
    spec: './cypress/e2e/cleanup.cy.js',        // your cleanup spec
  })
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

#### Some configuration:

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    excludeSpecPattern: ['cleanup.cy.js'],   // exclude this one from the normal run
  }
})
```

**package.json**

```js
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test:headless": "yarn cypress:run",
    ...
    "cleanup": "yarn ./scripts/e2e-run-cleanup.js",     // script to kick off
    "posttest:headless": "yarn cleanup",                // also after local run 
                                                        // "post" prefix automatically
                                                        // runs this after "test:headless" script 
    ...
  }
```

**main.yml**

```js
...
jobs:
  install:
    ...
  ui-chrome-tests:
    ...
  cleanup:
    ...
    needs: ui-chrome-tests        # ensure tests have run
    steps:
      - run: yarn cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the answer you are looking for, but maybe this information can be useful to you in some way:

One of the antipatterns I have heard multiple times from Cypress gurus is cleaning the application state using *after* or *afterEach* hooks.

If I remember correctly, the reasoning was that if the test fails or some step of the *after* hook fails, it will never get to the end of the script, thus we cannot be sure that the application state is prepared for the future tests.

That's why it is suggested to use *before* or *beforeEach* hooks, to prepare application state right before running tests.

If you decide to run some scripts before or after tests in different specs, then the support file can be useful, because it is rendered before each spec:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file

As a final thought, if you want something to happen before or after running Cypress, then maybe the best way to accomplish this is to prepare a separate script and run it using whatever you use to run Cypress (node, docker, etc.).

Sorry that this answer got so long :)

To conclude my thoughts:

1. Better prepare the state for the tests, not clean up after them
2. Separate scripts can be run before or after tests, and they do not have to be inside Cypress (using node, bash, docker...)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ! Honestly, I was thinking about something like this as a backup plan, but first I wanted to be sure I exhausted all the options that Cypress comes with :)

Comment: @NicoleMilea You’re welcome! I am happy that my answer was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [After Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api) for this use case:

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('after:run', (results) => {
    // run some code after the run
  })
}
```

or

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:run', (results) => {
        // run some code after the run
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is a good option, but please note that the docs page says:

"When running via cypress run, the event will fire each time cypress run executes. As a result, if running your specs in parallel, the event will fire once for each machine on which cypress run is called."

Comment: Yes, good point @Eva-AnnaKlugman . Thanks for pointing this out.